# Is there a pre-Internet term for "gamification"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology, neologisms, internet

***Gamification*** is a relatively new term which was coined and has been made highly popular in the Internet era. From the related  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamification) article:

> Though the term "gamification" was coined in 2002 by ***Nick Pelling***, a British-born computer programmer and inventor, it did not gain popularity until 2010.

The term has made it into recognized English Dictionaries. [Oxford Online Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gamification) defines it as:

> The application of typical elements of game playing (e.g. point scoring, competition with others, rules of play) to other areas of activity, typically as an online marketing technique to encourage engagement with a product or service

However, the concept of "gamification" itself is not new. Our parents and teachers, for instance, have constantly been rewarding or trying to recognize our useful participation and constructive contribution in one way or the other.

That said, it is implied that if you fail to perform up to the mark, you risk not getting the rewards or worse, having the rewards taken away from you.

Consider a few examples of gains and loses,

- ***You gain if***

  - You are the first to complete an assignment and win a certificate/extra grade points.
  - You assist you mother in maintaining the garden / walk your dog and get extra pocket money.
- ***You lose if***

  - You fail to complete and submit the assignment, lose some ranks in the Class Leader board and have your name added to the "Defaulters" list.
  - Your sibling perfectly completes a household task and pockets all the cash even those earmarked for you!

---

Today, ***Gamification*** would be *THE* term. But...

***Is there a proper term that conveys the concept of "gamification"/"gamifying something" before it became popular?*** (thanks to the Internet).

***Could [incentivize](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incentivize) be that term? Or are there other terms that aptly preceded gamification?*** (may be in the last few decades of 20<sup>th</sup> century)

#### Usage Sentence:

> Our parents and teachers used to __________ our routines , rewarding every useful contribution and penalizing unproductive actions.  Today, it's known as *gamification*!

---

**Clarification on the Usage Sentence above:**

The above usage sentence is tentative and please let it not mislead or restrict you. Answerers can give any example that fits this context.

Comment: Thanks for identifying Mr. Pelling as the guy responsible for this commercially necessary but aesthetically distressing word!  And, with @DanBron, cheers for posing a fine question!

Comment: I wonder if the stripes and chevrons and colors and badges on a military inform can be considered the Ur-example of gamification.

Comment: Oops. You edited to include your example. Then, it should be "positive reinforcement". What shall I do?

Comment: For children the point system was marked on a  "reward chart", and/or teachers used to hand out "gold stars"

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Yes! I remember getting Gold Stars for scoring 100% in tests. If only I could fit "award gold stars" into something more precise!

Comment: @BiscuitBoy Your question is a little confusing. Are you looking for a verb?

Comment: @Rathony - Yes, for my usage example. Otherwise, I am open to nouns/phrases (as suggested by Lynnjamin) too. You could suggest them all!

Comment: I am thinking about deleting my post as users not knowing the edit history will call me crazy. Positive/Negative reinforcement is the only term that can have connotations of +ve and -ve effects at the same time. "Turn it into a game" doesn't necessarily have a -ve connotation.

Comment: @Rathony - I personally think "inducement" (your original answer) was a good term. I checked out its meaning and synonyms and it is pretty close. If you can think of a better term, please feel free to post it

Comment: My trouble is, if I see this word, I am likely to pronounce the *a* as in "gam" and not as in "game".  (Rhymes with "ramify".)

Comment: It reminds me of the "Spoonful of Sugar" theory expounded in the song from _Mary Poppins_: "In every job that must be done, there is an element of fun/You find the fun and, snap, the job's a game." That sociological hypothesis was put forward in 1964.

Comment: @Rathony, the -ve (cool contraction, btw) aspect of such a game would be when you had to give your tiles to your brother because he did your assigned chores which you refused to do because you were watching the Six Million Dollar Man instead.

Comment: There is *playification* also but it might be even a newer term.

Comment: Not a source of an english term, but throughout the 20th century USSR had widespread 'socialist worker competitions' that were in essence large scale implementations of gamification, carefully designed to incentivize production and with lots of studies on how to best do it.

Answer (score 31):

I love the word gamify.  Before that we used to have to use the set phrase, **"Turn it into a game".**  My mom would say, "Okay kids.  Let's turn it into a game."  Then she would gamify our chores with little tiles for points and score cards for the week, with minimum number of tiles to earn for a popsicle, etc.

Your example sentence:

> Our parents and teachers used to ***turn our routines into a game*** , rewarding every useful contribution and penalizing unproductive actions. Today, it's known as *gamification*!

Comment: gamify (ˈɡemɪˌfaɪ) - v. To transform into the shape of an attractive [female leg](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gams).

Comment: The process of using  -ify and -ize to make nouns into verbs turns out to have been discussed at length, right on this very forum.

Comment: Also *make it into a game*

Comment: @jim, I realized that after I wrote my answer, but because I was quoting my mom, who preferred to turn things instead of make things, it felt  more natural.  And I like the idea of turning, because it conveys a sense of transformation rather than creation.

Comment: "Make a game of it", too. See also "sport".

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I'd assume it would be gammify. The m, since it is preceded by a "short" vowel and is in a stressed syllable, would be doubled before a suffix starting with a vowel. Hence you get /ˈgæmɪ̈ˌfaɪ/.

Comment: @Lynnjamin That process would accurately be described as "verbification" or "verbization" respectively.  The corresponding verbs are "verbify" and "verbize". In contrast, to "verb" a noun is to simply use the noun as a verb without adding any suffix at all to explicitly mark it as a verb. (The noun form for this is, of course the gerund "verbing").

Comment: @MontyHarder, I like that name of the process is an example of the process. I was amazed at the factors that contribute to how we choose whether -ify or -ize is used, and how we just know which one sounds right.  There is a squiggly logic to why when we make an idol of something we idolize it and not idolify (which is cute and modern sounding to me) and we can deputize someone but deify someone else.

Answer (score 17):

In the UK, the term "Brownie points" had pretty much the same meaning since the 1960s and was quite widely used. I always assumed the origin was from the "points and badges" awards in the junior division (Brownies) of the Girl Guide movement.

Wikipedia has some alternative etymological conjectures: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownie_points

(But it doesn't quite fit the OP's "usage sentence", since the noun "Brownie points" never got verbed.)

Comment: In the USA too.

Comment: @hatchet [Brownie points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownie_points) refers to the good will someone feels towards you when you help them in some way in the US. I don't believe it ever refers to actual rewards, even something as simple as a title. Indeed, it's often used to point out the intangible social reward for such a deed that receives no visible reward. I can't speak about the UK from experience, but I see no mention of a different meaning there on the Wikipedia page.

Comment: @jpmc26 - It's similar in the sense that they are **virtual** points, somewhat like reputation points on StackExchange sites, earned for doing something beneficial, although not as rigorously tallied. The main point of my comment though was to say that the answer isn't exclusive to the UK.

Comment: @hatchet But it's dissimilar in that "gamification" refers to actually putting visible (if not tangible) elements in place to track the rewards, while "brownie points" is just a vague good will toward a person who did something that helped you. Gamification is obvious, visible, measurable, quantifiable, provable. Brownie points are none of those.

Comment: @jpmc26: Until the popularity contests get started, at which time brownie points are all of the above. However, I agree the terms are different. Making a game of something is so the task itself is rewarding; the points or stars or whatever are just means to the end of having fun. With brownie points, the points themselves are often the objective; you don't earn brownie points with your boss because you enjoy it, but because you want a promotion.

Comment: Brownie points aren't the same as gamification. Gamification is attempting to turn a boring, monotonous task into something that is fun by through  the application of game-design elements and game principles. Brownie Points are the nebulous feelings of goodwill and camaraderie you might feel for a sycophant when they suck up to you. They are BROWNie point because you get them from BROWN-nosing. "A metaphorical image: when kissing the buttocks of another person, one's nose is liable to be covered in brown feces." These things aren't even tangentially related.

Comment: Maybe it's only a local meaning, but in the (UK) company I work for "getting brownie points" is a (usually pejorative) term for getting real rewards in terms of better funding for projects, cash bonus payments, etc. Everybody knows it's a stupid game, but the prizes are real so (almost) everybody plays it. The term "gaming the system" is also beginning to be used for exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 8):

Jean-Francois Lyotard wrote about the "sportification" (presumably the verb he used would have been *sportifier*) of society, in which things are stripped of their traditional character in the name of points, competition, and winners. Consider the way that "sports" themselves evolved from activities with a distinctly moral character (compare German academic fencing with sport fencing, for example, or English public-school ball games before and after the creation of the Football Association). It's a slightly different phenomenon though, and at least in Lyotard's eyes, strongly pejorative.

The Lyotard book in question is *The Postmodern Condition*, French edition 1979/English translation 1984, but it's been many years since college and I can no longer say how much of the above reflects Lyotard and how much reflects secondary literature on him (not to mention my own thoughts on the matter). But the word does appear there.

Comment: This is really interesting, and not something I've come across before. Can you add a couple references to your answer, so we can read up more? Thank you!

Comment: If I recall correctly, it's from *The Postmodern Condition*. Internet says publication date 1979, English translation 1984. Short but oh so painful to read in undergraduate philosophy.

Comment: That's information worth [edit]ing into your answer!

Comment: I can't find any references to "sportification" in *The Postmodern Condition*; did you actually locate it there? It certainly may have appeared in some of his later works, but your description sounds more like Baudrillard to me. The people most due credit for the concept of "sportification" are Allen Guttmann and Henning Eichberg. Eichberg in particular is a great read if you're interested in a postmodern interpretation of the world of sports. She sees sportification as part and parcel of a universal hegemonic trend of standardization and globalization, marking a "revolution of body culture."

Answer (score 7):

You could consider using [**inducement**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inducement) which means:

> something that gives you a reason for doing something and makes you
>   want to do it
>
> a motive or consideration that leads one to action or to additional or
>   more effective actions

Example:

> English Language and Usage offers reputation points and badges **as an
>   inducement** for users to keep visiting the site.

[Merriam-Webster]

**Edit**: Your example makes me wonder if *inducement* is the right word. In that case, you could consider using [**reinforcement**](http://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/positive+reinforcer) which means:

> a strengthening of a specific behavior due to its association with a stimulus. Reinforcement is an important part of operant or instrumental conditioning. A **reinforcer** is the stimulus that strengthens the behavior, in contrast to **punishment** that weakens the behavior.

Your new example:

> Our parents and teachers used reinforcement to **reinforce** our routines, rewarding every useful contribution (as positive reinforcement or reinforcer) and penalizing unproductive actions (as punishment).

Comment: I was thinking "enticement" but your "inducement" is a much better word, hands down! +1

Comment: Jeez, I have edited again... I want to convey both +ve and -ve effects, just like how gamification does (You can either gain or lose)

Comment: I can't tell if the OP is looking for *behavior modification* or what but you seem to have a single word for it, so plus one. Phrases before "gamification" include *gaming/playing the system* which this word also seems to fit, so plus two.

Comment: @Mazura Thanks. I thought about deleting it as the question was edited a few times.

Comment: The edits changed nothing. Your comment of "positive reinforcement" is also spot-on. Pavlov trumps Mary Poppins any day of the week. The question is flawed: what did we call [playing the system] before there were 'systems' is a non-starter: "typically as an online marketing technique to encourage engagement with a product or service". What did we call *that* before there was the internet? : We didn't. Behavior modification is called *conditioning* and is accomplished by (TIL) inducement.

Answer (score -1):

I think the word you need is 'fun'.  To make something 'fun' to do, is by implication turning it into play, or a game.

Comment: The *process* of making a chore *fun* is rarely fun, and that is the term that is sought.

Comment: The process of gamification is probably just a chore as well.  The intent is to 'create fun', and it was in that context that I was using it.  There is no verb 'funification', but the pre-internet use of 'to make something fun' is comparable to 'to gamify something'.